# How to GSON pretty print in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, gson, pretty-print

The below code to show JSON string in TreeView by Gson's prettyprinting() is added in JSP , but the treeview is only displayed in Tomcat console by the SOPs . BUT , in JSP the jsons are displayed as normal strings as shown in the attached screenshot : -

```
<% 
    for(String strCol : ResultSetColumnNames)
    {
        System.out.println("strCol = "+strCol);
    %>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><%=strCol%></td>  
    <%      
    String value = jo.get(strCol).getAsString();  //jo.get(strCol).toString();       
    if(strCol.contains("JSON"))
     { 
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(value);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String prettyJson = gson.toJson(jsonElement);
        System.out.println("PRETTY-"+strCol+" = "+prettyJson);
    %>    
      <td align="center"><div contenteditable="true"><%=prettyJson%></div></td>
    <%
     }
     else
     {
    %>
      <td align="center"><div contenteditable="false"><%=value%></div></td>     
    <%      
     }
    %>
     </tr>
    <%
   }
   %>
```

Please suggest , how to show JSON in treeview in JSP .

Thanks & Regards
Saswata Mandal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PChN0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Json gets displayed in TreeView format by adding **pre** tag around the prettyJson string as shown in the code below : -

```
<tr>
    <td align="center"><%=strCol%></td>  
    <%      
    String value = jo.get(strCol).getAsString();  //jo.get(strCol).toString();       
    if(strCol.contains("JSON"))
     { 
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(value);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String prettyJson = gson.toJson(jsonElement);
        System.out.println("PRETTY-"+strCol+" = "+prettyJson);
    %>
      <%-- After adding <pre> tag , JSON is displayed in TreeView format. Without it normal JSON string is shown --%>     
      <td><div contenteditable="true"><pre><%=prettyJson%></pre></div></td>
    <%
     }
     else
     {
    %>
      <td align="center"><div contenteditable="false"><%=value%></div></td>     
    <%      
     }
    %>
     </tr>
    <%
   }
   %>
  </table>
```